# Dynamically determining if application is Winform based or ASP.NET based

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms, n-tier-architecture

I have a data access layer that is compiled as a class library and compiles to a dll. Historically, the dll provided data access to my database for my web application. It works just fine, but what its doing is it is pulling my connection string from the web.config. This is fine too, but now I want to use this data dll in a Windows Form application. Is there a way for the DLL to know if its running inside a web application or winform application and to appropriately pull the connection string from either the web.config or app.config file?

Comment: The DLL will use the config file of the consuming application.  It doesn't matter if it's an app.config or web.config.  The DLL doesn't need to know and doesn't care if it's web or winforms.

Comment: I believe the answer from @Tim is correct. But just in case, please show your code where the config value is referenced.

Comment: @ShaiCohen -- The code I'm using is `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MMDatabase"].ConnectionString`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I put in my comment, a class library will use the configuration file of the application that is referencing it.  It doesn't matter if it's WinForms or a Web App.  As long as there's a config file, the library will be able to access it/use it.

That's one of the big advantages of using libraries for reusable code.

The caveat to this is to make sure that the correct information is in the config files (app or web) :)

Comment: So if I'm using this line: `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MMDatabase"].ConnectionString` then it will automatically know to use the right config file? Assuming the key name `MMDatabase` is valid in both config files?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, from a decoupling perspective, the best approach would be having the application which is using the DLL provide the connection string to the library.

Comment: I thought of this, but would I have to provide a connection string each time I instantiate my class or is there a global way of setting it once and be done with it?

Comment: You would have to provide it when you instantiate the class. However, this should probably happen only once during the application life cycle.